# AngularJs $http post not sending data to restful api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is my angular controller that performs the post function

```
app.controller ('accountsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    this.accounts = { code:"", account_name:"", description:"", account_type_id:"", is_active:"", user_id:"", owner_id:""};

    $scope.addPage = "#!/account";
    $scope.uploadPage = "upload.html";
    $scope.exportPage = "export.html";

   let user_token = local_store("get", "primalfitsUser").token;

    let headers = {
        "Content-Type":'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;',
        "Authorization":"Bearer "+user_token
    };

    $scope.account_save = function($http) {
        this.accounts.is_active = 1;
        console.log(this.accounts);
        // $http.post(base_api_url+"/accounts",$httpParamSerializerJQLike(this.accounts) ,{"headers":headers}).then(
        //         result => console.log(result)
        //     ).catch(error => console.log(error));


          $http({
            url: base_api_url+"/accounts",
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            data: {'message' : this.accounts},
            paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'

        }).then((result) =>{
            $scope.info = result.data.message;
        }, function(error){
            $scope.error = error;
        });
    };
```

Comment: How do you know that it's not sending a request? Did you check the **network** tab?

Comment: yes i did check the network tab,i console.log the data its getting from the frontend  console.log(this.accounts); and it shows it contains data but at the network tab, the rquest object contains empty array

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a `$http` local variable, maybe that is the problem?

```
 $scope.account_save = function($http) { // <- remove $http! it comes from the controller itself
        this.accounts.is_active = 1;
        console.log(this.accounts);
```

[reference jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Afroza/j35e8v8h/)

Comment: sorry that was a mistake...i have removed the $http local variable declaration and its still not working

Comment: @phenomT Please check the network tab if the call is made, I suspect `paramSerializer` is the problem, could you try removing that?

Comment: yes, about that av tried removing it, i used paramSerializer when i tried using the content type as "Content-Type":'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;

Comment: @phenomT What about network that, what error are you getting?

Comment: i have since then change it back to application/json and removed the paramSerializer and it still does not work

Comment: about the network is just returning error from the backend due to request validation because it cannot see any data from the frontend

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to perform post-function with this controller.
I changed the name of:

```
this.accounts =  { code: "", 
    account_name: "", 
    description: "," 
    account_type_id:"", 
    is_active:"", 
    user_id:"", 
    owner_id:""
};
```

To `this.account` (i.e. singular form of accounts) both on the ng-model collecting the information from the frontend and the data passed to http.
Thanks everyone.

A singular "s" has been troubling me for some time now.